Moveit2 Servo control my own robot not working
my goal is to control my robot arm with a game controller and moveit servo. I have written a hardware interface for my robot arm and created a moveit configuration. The controller type for the robot arm is joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController and velocity as command interface. The motion planning with moveit via rviz works without major problems. But the servo function of moveit does not work as expected. For the servo functionality, I created a servo node, a twist cmd publisher and edited the panda simulated configuration to fit my robot. Now to my problem. The twist commands are published as desired and moveit publishes the velocities and positions for the joints to the /controller/joint_trajectory topic. However, these commands are not forwarded to the hardware interface, so there is no movement. Am I missing something?
Some Infos:

ROS2 Humble
Middleware rmw_cyclonedds_cpp
Launchfile from moveit_servo tutorial example
Tested with MockController and own HardwareInterface for real robot arm

Thanks

For debugging I'd suggest to separate moveit from the ros2_control setup.
Can you move your robot by sending commands manually to the topic? Or using rqt_joint_trajectory_controller?

Thanks for the Answer. I have tried various ideas and i think i have found the problem. My hardware interface that handles the can communication is too slow. Moveit published the correct commands and sending commands manually didn´t work either. But when I disabled the can communication, the hardware interface gets the movement commands. Therefore, I assume that the hardware interface is too slow. Can anyone confirm this behaviour and possibly suggest a solution?

You can reduce the update rate of the controller_manager, then also your hardware component has more time per update cylce to finish the communication.
